# can't uninstall a harmful app

Tags: applications

[image: the image is a screenshot, captured after clicking a pop-up notification titled 'harmful app is running' like this]

<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

a pop notification is being shown about running a harmful app on my android phone Symphony H300 with an option disable. when I'm clicking disable, notification is disappeared and showing again after some time. If I click the notification two option is there, one is keep anyway(unsafe) and the other is uninstall. i'm clicking uninstall. but the notification is being shown again after some time.

Comment: Can't you just turn off it's SMS permission? Is this a system app?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- instead of uninstalling the app through the notification, uninstall the app directly from the "Apps" menu in your settings. Click "Settings", scroll down to "Apps", find the app in question and tap on it, depending on the specific version of Android you have the options will vary, but you should have an "uninstall" button. Press that.
- some apps are a bit nasty to remove and require root privilege. If the above doesn't work, consider rooting your phone so you can get at the app and uninstall it. This should only be required if the app came pre-installed on your phone, or if the app is truly being nasty and blocking the uninstall.